# I am getting gradle error Execution failed for task

Tags: android, compiler-errors, android-gradle-plugin

I am getting this error

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/android/volley/AuthFailureError.class
```

I attached my **`gradle`** please check and help me.

```
    android {
              useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
             }

       dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile files('libs/android-async-http-1.4.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/disklrucache-2.0.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-gson.jar')
    compile project(':linkedin-sdk')
    compile files('libs/PGSDK_V2.0.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:25.3.1'
    compile files('libs/okhttp-1.2.1-jar-with-dependencies.jar')
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.razorpay:checkout:1.4.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.2.1'

    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.0'


}
```

Comment: remove volley from lib folder .`compile files('libs/volley.jar')` and use   `compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'`

Comment: I am using linkedin sdk,inside linkedin adk also one volley compile is there and my app level I have one more volley dependency, How I can make for both single.

Comment: Okay. please show this structure. You should call there `compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'` .try this way.Let me inform.

Comment: I tried this its working now, Thanku so much @IntelliJ Amiy

Comment: whats problem there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove Below **jar** file from **`gradle`**

```
compile files('libs/volley.jar')
compile files('libs/google-gson.jar')
```

and compile below dependency

```
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.0'
```

Comment: I need to add app level gradle or project level gradle ?

Comment: yes you have to add these dependencies in app level gradle

Answer (score 1):

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.>
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   com/android/volley/AuthFailureError.class

**Remove**

```
 compile files('libs/volley.jar') // From local lib also
```

**Use**

```
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
```

> I am using linkedin sdk,inside linkedin adk also one volley compile is
>   there and my app level I have one more volley dependency.

You should call **`volley:1.0.0`** there.